# Remove unforgeted records

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `server` (
    `server_id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `server_name` varchar(15),
    `server_alias` varchar(50),
    `server_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `server_join` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
    `server_number_member` int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (`server_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `member` (
    `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `member_server` int(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Id server',
    `member_name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tên của member',
    PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

An I create table `VIEW` to get list server

```
CREATE VIEW `server_client` AS 
SELECT
    `s`.`server_id`            AS `server_id`,
    `s`.`server_name`          AS `server_name`,
    `s`.`server_alias`         AS `server_alias`,
    IF (`s`.`server_join` = 1, (COUNT(`m`.`member_id`) / `s`.`server_number_member` * 100) DIV 1, 100) AS `server_full`  
FROM (`server` `s`
    LEFT JOIN `member` `m`
        ON ((`m`.`member_server` = `s`.`server_id`)))
WHERE `s`.`server_status` = 1
```

Now, `server` table have 1 record:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|server_id|server_name|server_alias         |server_status|server_join|server_number_member|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|       1 | SV 01     | http://example.com/ |           0 |         0 |                 10 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In `member`table

```
------------------------------------------
| member_id | member_server | member_name|
|----------------------------------------|
|         1 |             1 | aaa        |
|----------------------------------------|
|         2 |             1 | bbb        |
|----------------------------------------|
|         3 |             1 | ccc        |
------------------------------------------
```

Result in `server_client` table

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| server_id | server_name | server_alias | server_full |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| NULL      | NULL        | NULL         |         100 |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

`server_full` is used to calculate the percentage of the number of members already in a server

I want to remove record NULL in `server_client` table
How to do it

Thank

Comment: Is a `left join` the right join you should be using?

Comment: use "group by `s`.`server_id`"

Comment: @AkshayH that right for me

Comment: @EdHeal I want to get list server, member can exist or non, so I using `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `COUNT()` you should also be aggregating over the servers with `GROUP BY`.  The following query should be along the lines of what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW server_client AS 
SELECT
    s.server_id AS server_id,
    s.server_name AS server_name,
    s.server_alias AS server_alias,
    IF (s.server_join = 1,
        (COUNT(m.member_id) / s.server_number_member * 100) DIV 1,
        100) AS server_full
FROM server s
LEFT JOIN member m
    ON m.member_server = s.server_id
WHERE s.server_status = 1
GROUP BY
    s.server_id,
    s.server_name,
    s.server_alias
```

The only issue you may have is with the sum conditional aggregation I have in my query.  In any case, I expect that the results from the above will at least start looking correct.

By the way, I removed all the backticks because you don't them and they are ugly.

Comment: Update your question and tell us what `server_full` is supposed to represent.  Show us data illustrating this point.

Comment: @Akshay H was help me, only add group by server_id

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That for answer before

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: You have mutilated the calculation. It was really just `GROUP BY s.server_id` missing in OP's query. But I definitely agree on superfluous backticks and parantheses. Without them the query is much more readable.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're wrong, because the OP was mixing aggregate and non aggregate columns, and the query would not even run on any other database.  We still don't know what the OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: You are right OP's query was missing `GROUP BY`. With `GROUP BY s.server_id` the query becomes completly valid according to standard SQL. The columns `s.server_name` and `s.server_alias` are functionally dependent on `s.server_id` and hence superfluous in `GROUP BY`. (Unfortunately most DBMS don't comply with the standard here, though.) OP's calculation looks fine to me too: For "server_join=1" servers get the ratio of existing and allowed members (`member` records vs. `server_number_member`). As Mr Ken said: "Akshay H was help me, only add group by server_id" :-)